# HttpWebRequest - Reuse TCP connections

Tags: tcp, httpwebrequest, connection

I'm using HttpWebRequest the way that you're meant to: disposing the response when I'm done with it, in the hope that this would make it reuse any available TCP connections, however it doesn't: it closes the connection after the response is received. I see this happening when I use TCPView.

Here's my HttpWebRequest code:

```
 private HttpWebResponse ExecuteRequest(String baseRelativeUri, String method, Ds postValues) {

        /////////////////////////////////////////
        // Set-up

        Uri uri = new Uri( _baseUri, baseRelativeUri );

        _cookies.ProcessDomains();

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create( uri );
        request.CookieContainer = _cookies;
        request.Method          = method;
        request.UserAgent       = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0";

        if( postValues != null ) SetPostContent( request, postValues );

        /////////////////////////////////////////
        // Response

        return (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    }

    protected HtmlDocument ExecuteRequestHtml(String baseRelativeUri, String method, Ds postValues, HttpStatusCode expectedStatusCode) {

        using(HttpWebResponse response = ExecuteRequest(baseRelativeUri, method, postValues)) {

            if( response.StatusCode != expectedStatusCode ) throw new WebException("Did not receive " + expectedStatusCode + " response.");

            /////////////////////////////////////////
            // HtmlDocument

            using(Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream()) {

                HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.Load( stream );
                return doc;
            }
        }
    }
```

According to MSDN, the HttpWebRequest.KeepAlive property is true by default, as is HttpWebRequest.Pipelines. So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I was hitting the "2 simultaneous connections per host" rule that HttpWebRequest respects.

The solution is to set this static property:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 15;
```

Sorted :)